# Framework to include multiple ASP.MET MVC 3 Projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, projects

I developed an ASP.NET MVC 3 WebApp using JQuery & xRM. Now client wants another WebApp which will connect to another datasource but hosted on the same IIS. I think they will request few other similar apps, some connecting to multiple datasources at the same time.

As far as management of these apps is concerned, it would be great if I could share most of the implementation rather than starting from scratch everytime. Apart from  data sources, it would be great if I could share common libraries & configurations. And off course admin view, something similar to "MVC Membership Starter Kit" project.

I looked into "Areas", & it could be the last easiest option. I also looked into IoC like Ninject which might help a little.

So has anyone come across any MVC 3 compatible framework which will allow to develop MVC app as a module?

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching on Matt's [blog](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=259) "MVC3 and MEF"  which suggests MFE could be the potential candidate. There is an another implementation from Maarten Balliauw called MEFContrib.MVC.

I can't really understand the which to choose out of them at this hour (1:40 AM with 2 martinis down). I also found a post on Matt's blog about support to "Areas" where he has dumped blog plugin/extension but the sample is in MVC2.

So if I can utilise MEFContrib.MVC and add Areas support as "parent/container" project, we could potentially create another "plugin" child project which would refernce parent DLL during development. For deployment, all we have to do (with Matt's implementation), dump plug-in (child) files (DLL & view) into "Areas" subdirectory & restart the application.

Does this sound like a possible solution?